# How multiple plots can be compared

Tags: vb.net, plot

I have two plots. and i have to compare these plots by making one plot.

example

```
    plot1  x range (0 - 50), some y-range

    plot2  x range (50 - 100), some y-range

    resultant plot x range (0 -100)
```

How this can be done?

Comment: In what language? With what data?

Comment: vb.net language. data like, two list surface and radius of two plot plot1 and plot2. values of these two list will be different for both plots. I have to make one plot for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or can you just do:

plot(x1,y1);

points(x2-50,y2);

More generally, you can plot any 2 things together.  You have to make the x and y scales constant across both plots.  Something like this should work:

# assume I have vars: x1 and x2 and y1 and y2

# figure out the range of all y vars

yRange = range(y1,y2)

xRange = range(x1,x2)

plot(xRange,yRange, type='n') #creates the axes but doesn't put any points on them

points(x1,y1)

points(x2,y2, col='red')

---

My apologies, I thought this was in the R group and answered based on that.